# Accessing blazor (wasm) injected objects in plain c# code as opposed to razor page

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

As an example the template generated code has

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

and this service is consumed here

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient Http
...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
}
```

Fine, but can I access that service from a plain c# file?

I tried hand typing what the @inject generates but this doesnt seem to work:-

```
[Inject]
HttpClient Http {get;set;};
```

EDIT - answer consolidated out of various comments and answers

When a dependency is instantiated by the DI system if its constructor has arguments that are classes or interfaces already registered  then

- those dependencies are themselves instantiated if not already done
- the instances are passed to the constructor on the original dep

this chain must be initiated by an `@inject / [inject]` somewhere on a blazor page.

So to take my example. If I have some code in a class called say, DbIo, that needs the HttpClient. Must do

```
public class DbIo{
     HttpClient _http;
     // constructor effectively announcing the dependencies
     public DbIo(HttpClient _http){
         _http = http;
     }
}
```

add

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<DbIo>();
```

to program.cs, and add (this is the not obvious bit)

```
 @inject DbIo DbService
```

to a blazor page (say App.razor). This forces the instantiation of a DbIo instance and hence the passing of the other services via its constructor.

Comment: Does plain old constructor injection not work?

Comment: @Moho yes, but it seems hacky to me (a non UI component that needs access to a service needs the cooperation of a UI component to supply it - not very cleanly layered)

Comment: @Moho I mean, where did the caller of the constructor get the service from? It seems like it has to be an `@inject` in a UI page

Comment: @Moho i just worked out what constructor injection means thanks to accepted answer, docs not clear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nature of Dependency Injection.  If the root object is provided by the DI Container, then it can resolve all constructor parameters, assuming that they too are registered in the DI Container.

Razor Components/Pages are provided by the Blazor framework and the Blazor framework takes care of resolving the Injected properties (assuming they have been registered in the DI container).

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
    new HttpClient 
    { 
        BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) 
    });
```

... adds HttpClient to the DI Container.

When your FetchData page is provided by the Blazor Framework it will provide services marked with directive *@inject*.  In this case ... HttpClient.

**Using a custom service ...**

If you want to use a service between your pages and HttpClient so that the page is not working directly with an HttpClient, then you'd need to register that service in the DI Container.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyCustomService>();
```

Then, in your razor page, you can inject MyCustomService:

```
@inject MyCustomService CustomService
```

Now that MyCustomService is being provided by the DI Container, it can just request the HttpClient in it's Constructor parameters (as the HttpClient is also registered in the DI Container):

```
public class MyCustomService
{
    readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    public MyCustomService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    public async Task ApiMethod()
    {
        await _httpClient.PostAsync( ..... );
    }
}
```

Comment: aha, now I see. Where is this documented, the fact that if I can add a service that needs other services and they will be wired up automatically. I looked long and hard

Comment: Start from here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: well I read that several times and did not get the trick here. I guess one of the reasons is the complex way they show getting IJSRuntime into pure c# files in the blazor JS interop docs. That surely could be accomplished by this mechanism.

Comment: Yes, IJSRuntime is added to the container by the Blazor framework so you can inject IJSRuntime into a razor component or any other c# class registered with the DI container.

Comment: I cant make this work. Does MyCustomService have to have an IMyCustomerService defined that it implements?

Comment: Nope.  Using interfaces allows interchangeable concrete implementors of that interface, but you can just register MyCustomService using the syntax in my answer.  That line should be added to Program.cs file, perhaps just after the HttpClient registration.

Comment: i discovered the trick, somebody has to @inject something in the dependency chain, Adding in program.cs alone doesnt trigger their instatiation ( I updted my question with an answer). Tx for you help

Comment: Correct.  "Adding" just means registering the details of the service with the DI container.  The DI container will not instantiate anything until it is asked to 'Resolve' a service.  That first request normally comes from framework (e.g. AspNet Controller or Razor Page, etc.).  Once you've asked for that root object to be resolved by the DI container, the DI will resolve the full dependency tree based on constructor parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when working with Blazor Wasm.

I used a workaround using a loading page and manually injecting what i needed from there in the OnInitialized() override method.

For some reason these flags didn't work in .cs files, but they always do in .razor. So, i injected them from a .razor page like a "Setup(neededObject)".

Comment: exactly what I did but it seemed a little hacky to me

Comment: @pm100 You could try injecting via constructor, though this didn't work for me, it could work for you.